# Custom trigger chip on ngFor chips

Tags: css, angular

I want to have a custom trigger chip that shows the remaining chips (i.e "+ 4 others) without truncating the text of the trips with ellipses, without overflowing to the next line, and while keeping the width of the card/parent container static.

CSS Code

```
.searchResultCard__chipWrapper {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.searchResultCard__chip {
  background: #8c8f93 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  text-align: center;
  height: 21px;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

HTML
Code

```
<div class="searchResultCard__chipWrapper">
  <div
    class="searchResultCard__chip"
    *ngFor="let apps of result.requirementSetApplications"
    matTooltip="{{ apps.title }}"
  >
    {{ apps.title }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was able to be resolved with the following code:

```
    <div class="searchResultCard__chipWrapper">
      <div
        class="searchResultCard__chip"
        *ngFor="let apps of result.requirementSetApplications | slice:0:limitTo" 
        matTooltip="{{ apps.title }}" 
      >
        {{ apps.title }} 
      </div>
      <div class="searchResultCard__chip" *ngIf="result.requirementSetApplications.length > limitTo">
        +{{result.requirementSetApplications.length - limitTo}} others
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) you could utilize.

```
  <div class="searchResultCard__chip"
      *ngFor="let apps of result.requirementSetApplications" | slice:0:limitTo>
        {{ apps.title }} +{{result.requirementSetApplications.length - limitTo}} others
  </div>
```

Where `limitTo` is a variable holding the maximum number of chips you want before your trigger. Of course you need to handle case when you have less than `limitTo` elements in your array